# possible to you add an external RF PA LNA to a chip that has internal PA LNA?

Tags: rf, wireless

I'm working with a new generation of a wireless chip that now has a built-in PA and LNA.

The trouble is that its sensitivity is -92dBm and my old version that did not have internal RF amplifier could do -104dBm when combined with external front-end components.

The PA portion is not the issue because their output is limited by FCC.  The difference in the LNA sensitivity has a big effect on the range.

Is it possible to re-gain our old link budget using a design with external PA/LNA in combination of the built-in set?

Comment: "The PA portion is not the issue because their output is limited by FCC." I'm not sure the FCC has any say on how much noise the PA introduces to the power supply of your LNA.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should be possible to increase the sensitivity of your system by putting a lower noise LNA in between an external antenna and the chip's internal LNA.

The noise figure and thus sensitivity of your system will be dominated by the noise of the first amplifier in the receive chain, see the pages on [noise figure](http://www.microwaves101.com/encyclopedias/noise-figure) and [cascade analysis](http://www.microwaves101.com/encyclopedias/cascade-analysis) by Microwaves101.  Your total system noise figure \$F\$ will be:

$$
F=F_1 + \frac{F_2-1}{G_1}
$$

where \$F_1\$ and \$G_1\$ is the noise figure and gain of the first LNA and \$F_2\$ is the noise figure of the second LNA.  In your case, \$F_2\$ is the noise figure of the internal LNA.

Your new chip's minimum receive power, ie. sensitivity, of -94dBm is related to noise figure by

$$
S_{min} = SNR_{min} k T_O B F
$$

where \$SNR_{min}\$ is the minimum signal-to-noise ratio of the receiver, \$k\$ is the Boltzmann constant, \$T_O\$ is the system temperature, \$B\$ is the system bandwidth, and \$F\$ is the receiver noise figure.  While you can't change the chip's \$SNR_{min}\$ you can possibly decrease the noise figure by using a lower noise external LNA.  Without more information it's hard to say what is the noise figure of the internal LNA so as to predict what the noise figure of the external LNA needs to be.

As a side note, I wouldn't neglect examining the filtering and impedance matching between the external antenna and chip, both can greatly influence the overall receiver sensitivity.

Comment: I don't think they've published the internal LNA info, but matching network information is there.  Thanks for the answer.